# Variable not found in asynchronous classes

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a little problem, in fact, I am trying to make the game of life but without searching on google and I would like to make two classes, the first one that proceed the tkinter app and the second one that proceed the game it self (moving cells...).

The fact is, when I try to implement a pause button, it doesn't works because of the while of the game class or its recursive function... Well, the process of the app is completly used by the loop.

I then tried to make it with asynchronous methods and to well understand them I tried with an own example :

`

```py
import asyncio
from async_class import AsyncClass

class Foo():
    async def __ainit__(self):
        self.test = 'Hi'
        return
    #
    def show(self):
        print(self.test)
#

class Bar():
    async def __ainit__(self):
        return
    #
#

async def main():
    foo = Foo()
    asyncio.create_task(foo.show())
    bar = Bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

`
Here I then have an error that says : AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'test'...

To you have any idea to fix that ? or even a ethod to permit a pause into the game ?

I hope you'll have a solution,

Thx

Comment: python doesn't use `__ainit__` function, it is never called, also `show` is not a coroutine, so it cannot be converted to a task, make `show` the async function and change `__ainit__` to just `__init__` without async and your code will work as intended, if you want to use the `__ainit__` function then you have to inherit AsyncClass, and you will have to await the constructor, which is not what you are doing,  anyway implementing the pause button is just that you won't advance the game state when paused ... you just wrap the physics and motion logic in a condition and not do it when paused ...

Comment: But if I use an __init__ rather than __ainit__ (method belonging to the async-class library) I will nomore be able to declare an asynchronous class... I am in need to ?

Comment: the code above looks like it is trying to use `__init__` ... so if your code needs to use `__ainit__` then use it, but you have to inherit AsyncClass.

Comment: OK thank you very match but hwo I am supposed to use AsyncClass ?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/async-class/#async-class

Comment: Ok but why I am supposed to use 
```async def __ainit__```
then .